# Objective-c: Problems with blocks and NSEnumerationConcurrent

Tags: objective-c, enumeration, objective-c-blocks

I have a dictionary containing a second dictionary with 1000 entries. The entries are all  NSStrings of the type key = `key XXX`, and value = `element XXX` where `XXX` is a number between 0 - the number of elements - 1. (Several days ago, I asked about Objective-C dictionaries containing a dictionary. Please [refer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5829240/298607) if you want the code that creates the dictionary.)

The sum total length of all the strings in the sub dictionary is 28,670 characters. ie:

```
strlen("key 0")+strlen("element 0")+
//and so on up through 
strlen("key 999")+strlen("element 999") == 28670.
```

Consider this a very simple hash value as an indicator if a method has enumerated every key+value pair once and only once.

I have one subroutine that works perfectly (using blocks) to access the individual dictionary key and values:

```
NSUInteger KVC_access3(NSMutableDictionary *dict){
    __block NSUInteger ll=0;
    NSMutableDictionary *subDict=[dict objectForKey:@"dict_key"];

    [subDict 
        enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:
            ^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
                ll+=[object length];
                ll+=[key length];
    }];
    return ll;
}
// will correctly return the expected length...
```

If I try the same using concurrent blocks (on a multi processor machine), I get a number close to but not exactly the expected 28670:

```
NSUInteger KVC_access4(NSMutableDictionary *dict){
    __block NSUInteger ll=0;
    NSMutableDictionary *subDict=[dict objectForKey:@"dict_key"];

    [subDict 
        enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:
            NSEnumerationConcurrent
        usingBlock:
            ^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
                ll+=[object length];
                ll+=[key length]; 
    }];
    return ll;
}
// will return correct value sometimes; a shortfall value most of the time...
```

The Apple docs for `NSEnumerationConcurrent` state:

```
 "the code of the Block must be safe against concurrent invocation."
```

I think that is probably the issue, but what is the issue with my code or the block in `KVC_access4` that is NOT safe for concurrent invocation?

**Edit & Conclusion**

Thanks to BJ Homer's [excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851206/objective-c-problems-with-blocks-and-nsenumerationconcurrent/5851403#5851403), I got NSEnumerationConcurrent working. I timed both methods extensively. The code I have above in `KVC_access3` is faster and easier for small and medium sized dictionaries. It much faster on lots of dictionaries. However, if you have a mongo big dictionary (millions or tens of millions of key/value pairs) then this code:

```
[subDict 
    enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:
        NSEnumerationConcurrent
    usingBlock:
        ^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
        NSUInteger workingLength = [object length];
        workingLength += [key length];

        OSAtomicAdd64Barrier(workingLength, &ll); 
 }];
```

is up to 4x faster. The crossover point for size is about 1 dictionary of 100,000 of my test elements. More dictionaries and that crossover point is higher presumably because of set-up time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With concurrent enumeration, you'll have the block being run simultaneously on multiple threads. This means that multiple threads are accessing `ll` at the same time. Since you have no synchronization, you're prone to race conditions.

This is a problem because the `+=` operation is not an atomic operation. Remember, `ll += x` is the same thing as `ll = ll + x`. This involves reading `ll`, adding `x` to that value, and then storing the new value back in `ll`. Between the time that `ll` is read on Thread X and when it is stored, any changes caused by other threads will be lost when Thread X gets back to storing its calculation.

You need to add synchronization such that multiple threads can't be modifying the value at the same time.  The naive solution is this:

```
__block NSUInteger ll=0;
NSMutableDictionary *subDict=[dict objectForKey:@"dict_key"];

[subDict 
    enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
    usingBlock:
        ^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
            @synchronized(subDict) { // <-- Only one thread can be in this block at a time.
                ll+=[object length];
                ll+=[key length];
            }
}];
return ll;
```

However, this discards all the benefits you get from concurrent enumeration, since the entire body of the block is now enclosed in a synchronized block—in effect, only one instance of this block would be actually running at a time.

If concurrency is actually a significant performance requirement here, I'd suggest the following:

```
__block uint64 ll = 0; // Note the change in type here; it needs to be a 64-bit type.

^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
    NSUInteger workingLength = [object length];
    workingLength += [key length];

    OSAtomicAdd64Barrier(workingLength, &ll); 
}
```

Note that I'm using `OSAtomicAdd64Barrier`, which is a fairly low-level function that is guaranteed to increment a value atomically. You could also use `@synchronized` to control the access, but if this operation is actually a significant performance bottleneck, then you're probably going to want the most performant option, even at the cost of a bit of clarity. If this feels like overkill, then I suspect enabling concurrent enumeration isn't really going to affect your performance all that much.